# Destroying background of Activity

Tags: java, android

My application contains more than 10 activities with backgrounds. The problem is that when I click on button to move to another `Activity` my app crash because I don't release enough memory for the app. Please show me clearly how I can write the code to destroy the background of `Activity` (A) before the `Activity` (B) start.

PS : Somme one told me that you must use this code `view.setBackgroundResource(0)` & I don't know where I must write the code in java, please show me clearly how I can do that??

I don't know if i use this java code:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: use `finish();` after `startActivity(intent);`

Comment: did you mean :  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

Comment: yup. once you have started another activity, you must end the previous activity if you do not require to traverse back to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to destroy the background activities yourself, the android system will do it for you. When an activity is no longer in use, the system will automatically destroy it.

`view.setBackgroundResource(0)` is used for clearing a view's background.

By the way, you said your app crash because of low memory, maybe it is an ANR, but 10+ activities should not case exception. So it's better to put the logs.

Comment: it still stores the activity in the backstack

Answer (score 0):

This is a very large topic covered extensively in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html). Specifically in the section titled [Managing Bitmap Memory](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html). I suggest you read through this documentation, especially if you want to handle the loading, caching and garbage collection of bitmaps yourself.

Otherwise, I suggest you adopt one of the many libraries that will handle all of this for you. For example; [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco).